# Get the index of the click element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

I am trying to get the index of the clicked element but I keep getting `-1` in the console. I am using `Array.prototype` to get the `indexOf` from the `nodelist`

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
  <div app-click="">
    <div ng-repeat="json in myJson">
      <li>{{json}}</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
.directive('appClick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      $element.bind("click",function(e){
            var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call($element.children(), e.target);
          console.log(index);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oyvr85e2/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other option is to set the index

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
  <div app-click="">
    <div ng-repeat="json in myJson">
      <li data-index="{{$index}}">{{json}}</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and read it in the click

```
e.target.dataset.index
```

Comment: Should have thought about this! Thank you.

Comment: this is having a different behavior on keypress.. if i want the enter key to have the same behavior as the click... I get undefined when I press enter but the right e.target when i click

Comment: How does an li have a key press?

Comment: if I tab on to it... and press enter... I have set up tabindexes on to my container and it's child elements

Comment: so what is e.target? Problem is not the index, issue would be the fact how you bound the event.

Comment: On keypress, e.target is the parent while on its the child

Comment: Why are you not using ng-click?

Answer (score 2):

`e.target` return li element,$element.children()  return `div`list not `li`
try this code:

```
var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call($element.find("li"), e.target);
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myJson = ["mayank1", "mayank2", "mayank3", "mayank4", "mayank5", "mayank6", "mayank7", "mayank8", "mayank9"]
})

.directive('appClick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      $element.bind("click",function(e){
        var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call($element.find("li"), e.target);
          console.log(index);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
  <div app-click="">
    <div ng-repeat="json in myJson">
      <li>{{json}}</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One question. What if I have multiple li's and I want to go to a specific li with class="list1"

Comment: And also... can you put an explanation of why $element.children() is not working?

Comment: You can use `.find("li[class='list1']")` to find out the element

Comment: @user4756836 $element.children()  return `div`list not `li` ,and e.target return li element